# Property 'array' does not exist on type 'FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms'

 ngOnInit() {
    this.subjectDesigneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.subjectDesigneForm.array([this.createItem()])
    });
  }
```

> items: this.subjectDesigneForm.***array***([this.createItem()])

when i write this line error accrues Property 'array' does not exist on type 'FormGroup

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using is incorrect.

You need to use `this.formBuilder.array` instead of `this.subjectDesigneForm.array`.

Modify your code as following :

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms'

ngOnInit() {
  this.subjectDesigneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.array` is not available on `FormGroup` but on `FormBuilder`. You need to do: `this.formBuilder.array()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TwitterServiceService} from 'src/app/services/twitter-service.service';
import { Twitter} from '../model/Twitter.model';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-twitter',
  templateUrl: './twitter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./twitter.component.css']
})
export class TwitterComponent implements OnInit{
twitter! :Array<Twitter>;
searchFormGroup! : FormGroup;
constructor(private twitterService:TwitterServiceService, private fb: FormBuilder){}
ngOnInit():void{
this.searchFormGroup=this.fb.group({
keyword : this.fb.control(null)
});
this.twitterService.getAllTwitter().subscribe({
next :(data)=>{
this.twitter=data;
}
});

}
handleDeleteTwitter(t:Twitter){
let conf=confirm("etes vous sur de vouloir supprimer")
if(conf==false)return;
this.twitterService.deleteTwitter(t.id).subscribe({
next :(data)=>{
let index=this.twitter.indexOf(t);
this.twitter.splice(index,1);

}
})
}

handleSearchTwitter(){
// let keyword =this.searchFormGroup.keyword;
// this.twitterService.searchTwitter(keyword).subscribe({
//  next :(data)=>{
// this.twitter=data;
//  }
// })
}
}
 hello this is my code source and its sayingerror TS2339: Property 'keyword' does not exist on type 'FormGroup<any>'.

37 let keyword =this.searchFormGroup.keyword;
                                     ~~~~~~~
any help please
```